# Dynamic JPA 2.0 query using Criteria API

Tags: java, dynamic, jpa, criteria-api, jpa-2.0

I am a bit stucked constructing a dynamic query using the CriteriaBuilder of JPA 2.0.

I have quite a common use case I guess: User supplies a arbitrary amount of search parameters X to be and / or concatenated: like :

```
select e from Foo where (name = X1 or name = X2 .. or name = Xn )
```

The Method or of CriteriaBuilder is not dynamic:

Predicate or(Predicate... restrictions)

Ideas? Samples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case, I would rather use [`Expression#in(Collection)`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html#in(java.util.Collection)) to avoid having to loop and to build a compound [`Predicate`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Predicate.html) dynamically:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Foo> cq = cb.createQuery(Foo.class);
Metamodel m = em.getMetamodel();
EntityType<Foo> Foo_ = m.entity(Foo.class);
Root<Foo> foo = cq.from(Foo_);
cq.where(my.get(Foo_.name).in(params));
```

You might want to check [Basic Type-Safe Queries Using the Criteria API and Metamodel API](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html) for more details.