# Implementing Query By Example functionality in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Do you know a way of implementing something like a Hibernate `QBE` (Query by Example) in JPA?

For my problem domain the alternative of using it will be to build a SQL query dynamically using some sort of string manipulation, something I would like to avoid.

I know this is not supported by default in the API, but I recognize it as a great technique for building dynamic queries.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In JPA 2.0 the closest equivalent is called the **Criteria API**. It did not exist in JPA 1.0.

Here is a sample:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery c = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
Root person = c.from(Person.class);
c.select(person)
    .where(cb.equal(person.get("name"), "Officer Friendly"));
```

Comment: Thank U very much for the example, thats the thing, I'm not using JPA 2.0 but 1.0

Comment: One of the main advantages of FindByExample is that you are free to refactor the entity without having to worry about breaking the queries that rely on FindByExample. In this example you see that if Person "name" gets refactored splitting it into "firstName" and "lastName" the query will be broken.

Answer (score 9):

QBE is not available in JPA 1.0 or 2.0. For more details look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880209/jpa-findbyexample)

Comment: I think this is the correct answer but unfortunately it is in the hands of the OP to pick the right one. I upvoted yours.

Answer (score 1):

I was in facing this same issue  a while back.

I found that using the JPA Criteria API was a bit cumbersome, so I decided to make an abstraction on top of it.

It is a small, flexible and simple library: https://github.com/kenglxn/QueryByExample

Hopefully it can be useful for others with this same issue.

The test case has several practical examples: https://github.com/kenglxn/QueryByExample/blob/master/src/test/java/net/glxn/qbe/QBETest.java

Comment: Will entities having collection properties are also supported? How about properties with deeper graph?

Comment: not currently, but feel free to post an issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago i had to scratch that ich and i decided to do it myself.

you can get it at sourceforge:
svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/jpaco/code/ jpaco-code