# JPA equivalents to Hibernate org.hibernate.criterion.Example?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, migration

I have an application that uses Hibernate. We are moving to JPA 2.1 standard.
There are a lot of usage of "org.hibernate.criterion.Example" with its (excludeProperty) feature. Is there any equivalent to "Hibernate Example" in JPA 2.1?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately no - this hasn't changed since JPA 2.0. But you can check the anwers in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880209/jpa-findbyexample). I would guess for simple use cases you can build something like _wallenborn_ is creating there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA doesn't offer this yet, but you can use Spring Data JPA [Query by Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example).

Comment: I would think that JPA will contain a solution by now - since Hibernate 6 has removed Example. I am looking for a way to replace our usage of Example...