# Is there a way to query by example in Jooq?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I've a `PersonPojo` and `PersonRecord` generated by Jooq.

Now I'd  like to to something like this:

```
Person p = new PersonPojo()
p.setId(10);
create.selectFrom(Tables.PERSON).whereLike(p).fetch();
```

Is it possible with the current version (3.7)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### jOOQ 3.8+ solution

[Query By Example (QBE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_by_Example) support was implemented in jOOQ 3.8 with [#4735](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4735). You can write:

```
Person p = new PersonPojo();
p.setId(10);

PersonRecord record = new PersonRecord();
record.from(p); // Reuse pre-existing reflection functionality here.

create.selectFrom(Tables.PERSON).where(DSL.condition(record)).fetch();
```

For more details, please refer to the [Javadoc](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#condition-org.jooq.Record-):

#### jOOQ 3.7 or less solution

In older jOOQ versions, you can implement QBE yourself:

```java
Person p = new PersonPojo();
p.setId(10);

PersonRecord record = new PersonRecord();
record.from(p); // Reuse pre-existing reflection functionality here.

Condition condition = DSL.trueCondition();
for (Field<?> field : record.fields())
    if (record.getValue(field) != null)
        condition = condition.and(((Field) field).eq(record.getValue(field)));

create.selectFrom(Tables.PERSON).where(condition).fetch();
```

#### Or, using Java 8:

```java
create.selectFrom(Tables.PERSON)
      .where(Stream.of(record.fields())
                   .filter(f -> record.getValue(f) != null)
                   .reduce(
                        DSL.trueCondition(),
                        (c, f) -> c.and(((Field) f).eq(record.getValue(f))),
                        (c1, c2) -> c1.and(c2)
                   ))
      .fetch();
```

Comment: That's not really what I wanted. I want something like this in jooq: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2883478/5553845 .So you can create any Person objects - use that as a filter and create a SQL and run it.

Comment: @UserX: OK, I wasn't aware of QBE as a formal concept. Interesting. Would be nice to add support for that in jOOQ, natively. I've updated the answer.

Comment: That's what I was expecting. Thanks for the answer. I tried to build something like that - but was not aware of the `DSL.trueCondition();` method.