# How to dynamic generate JOOQ condition?

Tags: jooq

I have some params to generate different sql condition,

```
Condition con = DSL.trueCondition();
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(book.getName)) {
  con = con.and(BOOK.NAME.eq(book.getName))
}
if (book.getId > 0) {
  con = con.and(BOOK.ID.eq(book.getId))
}
if ...
```

I want to know if there is common function, so I can dynamic generate condition. for example:

```
public Condition generateCondition(Field<?> field, Object obj, Class<?> type) {
  if () { 
    return DSL.trueCondition();
  }
  return field.eq(obj, type);
}
```

I have see this question [Is there a way to query by example in Jooq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667182/is-there-a-way-to-query-by-example-in-jooq), it's useful for search single table, but when I need search from multiple table, I don't know how to do...

Comment: Well, you already wrote the "common function". What's still missing?

Comment: actually, I don't konw how to write the function,  I just show the pseudocode

Comment: Well, what *exactly* does your function have to do? Auto-join? Auto-semi-join? Auto-project? Auto-filter? Auto-group-by? And which part of these possible specifications did you struggle with?